# My patience is running out

Tags: translation

How can I say my patience is wearing thin or my patience is running out.

I guess if I were to translate it, I'd say

我的耐心越来越少

That doesn't seem right

Answer (score 3):

`我快没耐心了`
or
`我等不及了`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You would say:

我快要失去耐心了。

or

我的耐心快要用完了。

BTW, your sentence "我的耐心越来越少" is also a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

我快要生气了，literally means I'm almost angry. This is particularly said by a mom when she is losing patience with her kids.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use the following sentences, which sounds more Chinese:

```
我越来越不耐烦了。
我的耐心是有限的。
```

Answer (score 1):

我正在失去耐心.......................

Answer (score 1):

There's a idiom which can be translated to "I can't wait":

我迫不及待。
(wo po bu ji dai)

:)

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion will be ..我的耐心快被磨尽了[my patience is wearing thin],

i hope it helps.. if wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

我快没耐心了  this is one correct answer.